# Angular Title, Meta Title and Description binding

Tags: html, angularjs

I am using Angular 1.4.8 with Bootstrap and I did binding for my title, meta title and meta description as shown below

```
<meta name="title" content="{{metadata.title}}" ng-if="metadata.title" />
<meta name="description" content="{{metadata.description}}" ng-if="metadata.description" />
<title>{{pageTitle}}</title>
```

I bind them from the js file in the state provider. Example:

```
.config(function($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('url', {
      url: '/url'
      ,title : "TITLE",
      metadata : {
          "title": "TITLE2",
          "description": "DESCRIPTION"
      },
    });
```

The problem with this is when I load on mobile phone, the mobile phone captured {{pageTitle}} as the title instead. What should I do to ensure the title can be loaded while keeping the title and the info dynamic?

Thanks!

Comment: You miss quotation marks. it's "DESCRIPTION but should be "DESCRIPTION".
Could you add jsfiddle or more html code in question?
Were you add ng-app attribute? In your case it should be in html tag.

Comment: For the first time page load you can have metadata.description already assigned to a default value, and after that it would be dynamic for other routes.